# what is the better way to block CIDR ranges in nginx when using proxy_protocol?

Tags: nginx, proxy-protocol, real-ip

I have a small pool of nginx instances that are behind an ELB in AWS. This ELB is internet-facing and speaks PROXY protocol, not HTTP.

Here's the relevant section of my `main.vhost`

```
server {

    # speak only PROXY protocol
    # Accept 80/443; we'll do the http -> https re-dir elsewhere in conf
    # SSL is default mode
    listen 443 default_server ssl proxy_protocol;
    listen 80 proxy_protocol;
```

I am trying to use the `deny` directive from the `ngx_http_access_module` to prevent access to a range of CIDR blocks.

E.G.: 
in a `.conf` file loaded by nginx at startup:

```
include /etc/nginx/ip_block/*.conf;
```

and in the `/etc/nginx/ip_block/` dir there is at least one file:

```
$ cat /etc/nginx/ip_block/some_cidr_ranges.conf | wc -l
361
$ head /etc/nginx/ip_block/some_cidr_ranges.conf
deny 2604:a880:1::/48;
<snip>
deny 208.68.36.0/22;
```

However, it appears that nginx's `deny` directive only works with the `$remote_addr` variable and does not work with the `$proxy_protocol_addr` variable.  This effectly means that I can not use both the `deny` directive and the `proxy_protocol` together.

It appears as though the `ngx_stream_realip_module` module can be used to adjust the values of `$remote_addr` to the `$proxy_protocol_addr` value however, the build of nginx I have available to me is not currently configured with the `--with-stream_realip_module` build-flag.  I am currently running `1.10.3` but it looks like the `with-stream_realip_module` flag was introduced in build `1.11.4` (https://github.com/nginx/nginx/commit/fe2774a9d689fa1bf201dd0e89449e3d9e4ad926)

*Option 1:* Build a version of nginx from source with the features i need compiled in.

While looking at the documentation for the `deny` directive, I found this note:

```
In case of a lot of rules, the use of the ngx_http_geo_module module variables is preferable.
```

From: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html

Which makes me wonder if there is a better way to achieve my goal of blocking CIDR ranges that may work with the binary of nginx that i currently have.

Could i try something like this:

```
geo $proxy_protocol_addr $blocked_cidr {
    default        01;
    include        conf/some_cidr_ranges_to_block.conf;
}
```

where the file `conf/some_cidr_ranges_to_block.conf` looks like:

```
2604:a880:1::/48    02;
<snip>
208.68.36.0/22      02;
```

and then in my server directive i could do something like:

```
if ($blocked_cidr != 01) {
 return 403;
}
```

*Option 2:* Attempt to use the `geo` directive and a custom IP range -> "country code" database to block traffic.

**My questions:**

```
- Is *option 1* going to be a better use of time / is it worth it to build my own version of nginx with the necessary `stream_realip_module` compiled in or is it going to be more performant / effective to use the `geo` directive to map the `$proxy_protocol_addr` onto a set of ranges as shown above (*option 2*) 


- Is there some other way to block or filter traffic in nginx by cidr block when using nginx in `proxy_protocol` mode that i have not yet considered?
```

Comment: You can also consider using `set_real_ip_from`, `real_ip_header` & `real_ip_recursive` to set the "right" `$remote_addr`.

Comment: @Tan Hong Tat - Thanks!   I'm not sure how i missed that in the documentation... i spent quite a lot of time searching through it for a solution before posting here.  a  `real_ip_header proxy_protocol ` configuration directive looks like it would have worked wonders!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick update / answer to my question.

Thanks to the suggestion from Tan Hong Tat, there is no need for me to compile my own version of nginx.   This takes *option 1* off the table and saves me some work. Thanks!

I have loaded a few hundred `deny` rules into nginx and I am keeping an eye on performance impact.

Additionally, I have implemented something that looks like *option 2* from my OP using the `geo` directive.  I am similarly monitoring impact.

So far, it is not clear to me why the nginx documentation issues the suggestion about using `deny` with "lots" of rules:

```
In case of a lot of rules, the use of the ngx_http_geo_module module variables is preferable.
```

The `geo` directive does allow me a bit more flexibly in that i can choose which where to send users.  The `deny` directive is a 403 and can not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use -

`if ($proxy_protocol_addr != a.b.c.d) {`
`return 403;`
`}`